# Gentzen's system of sequents provability

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

$\{p,q\to p,\neg q\}\vdash\{p,q\}$
Is it provable in Gentzen's system  ?
**My trial:**
$$\frac{p\vdash p,q\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{p\vdash p,q}{p,\neg q\vdash p,q}}{p,q\to p,\neg q\vdash p,q}$$
So, I think that answer is yes - Am I ok ?

**After hint:**
$$\overline{\{p\}\vdash \{p\}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \{p\}\vdash \{p\}}(axioms)$$$$\overline{\{p\}\vdash\{p,q\}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \{p\}\vdash\{p,q\} }(Weakness)$$
$$\overline{\{p\},\neg q\vdash \{p,q\}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \{p\}\neg q\vdash \{p,q\}}(\neg Left )$$ $$\overline{\{p,\neg q\},q\to p\vdash \{p,q\}} (\to Left)$$

Comment: Can you show me how to prove it ?

Comment: In particular I don't know how to understand $p,q\to p, \neg q $? Is it about $p\wedge q\to p\wedge \neg q $ ?

Comment: @EvanAad: In the Gentzen style system the OP is working with, the commas on the right-hand side of the turnstile denote disjunctions not conjunctions. In such a system $p \vdash p, q$ is an axiom.

Comment: ... or rather is deducible from an axiom using weakening on the right.

Comment: @RobArthan check it again please,  (edition)

Comment: Your attempt after the hint starts off right using the axiom $p\vdash p$ and then doing a WR, but goes wrong after that (it is very unclear what rules you are trying to use). All you need to do after the WR is to do WL twice to add the extra formulas $q \to p$ and $\lnot q$ on the right (you could do something more complicated, but there is no need to).

Comment: Lets try read this tree from down to up. Firstly I am using $\to $ rule, and then I have the same expressions - so I evaluate only one. Why it is not ok ?

Comment: It's not a proof tree. Try writing down alongside each horizontal line the name of the rule you are using.

Comment: Ok, I edited my first post. look again please

Comment: It's OK (although you still haven't drawn it as a tree). but in [LK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#The_system_LK), you can do it much more straightforwardly just with WL and WR. As you haven't said exactly what system you are working in, I can't say much more.

Comment: Yes, I provide in my notebook two solutions :) Could you glance at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967039/gentzens-system-provaility-of-two-formulas?noredirect=1#comment4037932_1967039 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking at Gentzen's system [LK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#The_system_LK) or some similar system.
In this system $p,q\to p,\neg q\vdash p,q$ may be deduced from the axiom $p \vdash p$ by repeated application of the rules WL and WR for weakening on the left and on the right.

To explain this to people who have claimed the sequent is not valid: the commas in this system denote conjunctions on the left of the turnstile but denote **disjunctions** on the right.

Comment: What about after my edition ? Correct ?