# Gentzen's system - provaility of two formulas

Tags: logic

I consider if following formulas are deducable in Gentzen's system:
(a) $(p\to q)\vee (q\to p)$
(b) $(p\to (q\to p))\to p$

**My approach**
(a)
$$\overline{p\vdash p\  \ \ \ \ \ q\vdash q}$$  $$\overline{p,q\vdash \{p,q\}} $$
$$\overline{p\vdash q\to p, \{q\}} $$
$$\overline{p\vdash q,\{q\to p\}} $$
$$\overline{\vdash p\to q ,\{q\to p\}} $$
$$\overline{\vdash p\to q \vee q\to p} $$
(b)

$$\overline{\vdash p\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (q\to p)\vdash p}$$
$$\overline{(p\to (q\to p))\vdash p}$$
$$\overline{\vdash (p\to (q\to p))\to p}$$
Ok, so $$\vdash p$$  can't be deducable in Gentzen's system.

Am I ok ?

Comment: Of course we cannot derive $\vdash p$, because $p$ is not a *tautology*.

Comment: Ok, (b) is correct. What about (a) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA help me, please